# Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin not appearing in Dynamics 365 app for phone

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, bing-maps

I'm currently trying to add Pushpins to a Bing map in a Dynamics 365 form.

While it is going smoothly for both computer & mobile web based versions, I'm facing an issue with the Dynamics 365 app for phone.

I checked the mobile option on both the HTML webresource and form I'm using, so my problem does not come from that.

This is my HTML file:

```
<body onload="loadMap();">
  <div id="myMap"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadMap() {
      if (window.top.mainAddress== null) {
        setTimeout(loadMap, 300);
        return;
      }
      
      Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Search', () => {
        let map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
          mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.aerial,
          zoom: 3
        });

        window.top.createMarker = (lat, lon, url) => {
          try {
            let marker = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(lat, lon), {
              color: "blue"
            });
            Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(marker, 'click', () => {
              window.open(url);
            });
            map.entities.push(marker);
            return true;
          }
          catch (exception) {
            return exception;
          }
        }

        let searchManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Search.SearchManager(map);
        let requestOptions = {
          bounds: map.getBounds(),
          where: window.top.mainAddress,
          callback: answer => {
            map.setView({ bounds: answer.results[0].bestView });
            map.entities.push(new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(answer.results[0].location, { color: "yellow" }));
          }
        };
        searchManager.geocode(requestOptions);
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?key=XXX" async="" defer=""></script>
</body>
```

And my JS file, with both functions called when the form load:

```
function getMainAddress(executionContext) {
  let formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
  window.top.mainAddress = [
    formContext.getAttribute("address1_line1").getValue(),
    formContext.getAttribute("address1_postalCode").getValue(),
    formContext.getAttribute("address1_city").getValue(),
  ].filter(Boolean).join(' ');
}

function secondaryMarkers(executionContext) {
  if (window.top.createMarker == null) {
    setTimeout(() => secondaryMarkers(executionContext), 500);
    return;
  }

  Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("lead", "?$select=address1_latitude,address1_longitude&$top=5").then((result) => {
    result.entities.forEach((lead) => {
      alert(window.top.createMarker(lead.address1_latitude, lead.address1_longitude, `https://XXX.crm.dynamics.com/main.aspx?pagetype=entityrecord&etn=lead&id=${lead.leadid}`));
    });
  }).catch((exception) => {
    alert(exception);
  });
}
```

So this is how it's supposed to work (Obviously in a non-optimal way but right now I just want this to work properly first): The `getMainAddress` function sets the `window.top.mainAddress` value while `loadMap` is waiting. Once the value is set, the map is created, the ````createMarker``` function is too, and the yellow pushpin representing the current lead is added to the map.

This part acutally works for both the web version of dynamics (On mobile & on laptop) and the Dynamics 365 app for phone.

After that, the `secondaryMarkers` function calls the `createMarker` function with the coordinates of 5 other leads.

My problem is that this function does `alert(true)` for every environments, but the blue pushpins do not appear in the Dynamics 365 app for phone, while they are visible in the web version (Be it on a laptop or on a phone).

Any idea of what I am doing wrong here ?

Does this problem comes from my code are from the Dynamics app ?

If it is the former, how do I add pushpins to a bing map ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after running differents tests it seems only the first element pushed in the `map.entities` collection is rendered in the Dynamics 365 app for phone.

I ended up using a `Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection` in which I pushed the pushpins and it worked.